# I am generating a pin code but for ease of users I want it to be a valid English word of any length. Any suggestions which api or util to use in JAVA?

Tags: java

I am generating a pin code but for customer ease i want to generate a valid English word of any length. Any suggestions which api or util to use for that purpose in JAVA? Thank you in advance!

Comment: As has been said before -- this is a very bad idea and exposes the pin to an easy hacking attack.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: If you're on linux, you can see if you have `dict`.

Comment: Well, I am also generating a random url and with each url a pin will be associated. URL is sent thru mail but PIN will be texted on their cells. So it wont be an easy hacking attack since my URL is also random.

Comment: @devnull... Just let me know how to go about it? Or random number as PIN is fine?

Answer (score 5):

> Any suggestions which api or util to use for that purpose in JAVA?

Main suggestion ... don't do it. It should be up to the end user to think up a passphrase. Any systematic scheme you implement for generating passphrases will be vulnerable to someone attacking your system.

I am not aware of an API or utility that does this. But if you did find such an API or utility, you should immediately be suspicious of it:

- any "common" scheme for generating passphrases will attract attention from people trying to defeat it
- you should be concerned that someone has incorporated a backdoor in the scheme.

The second problem is that a generated passphrase consisting of random English words won't be memorable, and hence the user is likely to write it down.  Once they have done that, your security is defeasible by looking for bits of paper in their stolen wallet, etcetera.

---

> Well, I am also generating a random url and with each url a pin will be associated. URL is sent thru mail but PIN will be texted on their cells.  So it wont be an easy hacking attack since my URL is also random.

If someone can access the user's browser history, or snoop his network traffic, then they can find out what the random URL is.

---

> Or random number as PIN is fine?

A randomly generated PIN is probably better than a non-random one (or one supplied by the user!) but neither is up to scratch ... unless they have 10+ digits.